# Lyx and finder MacOS

Tags: lyx, macos, wysiwyg

I've got an exam tommorow, the last couple of days Lyx has been really slow in navigating around finder. Say I wanna insert a graphic, it's slow in loading the folders.

Any tips or tricks? I tried running the full Onyx maintenance package, but it didn't really help anything. I reinstalled MacTex and lyx yesterday evening which didn't fix it either...

Comment: I added it on reddit if you wanna see the video.

https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/c42avs/lyx_and_finder_macos/

Comment: The picture are in general screenshots that are around 300-400 kb's in size, so I'm afraid that solve the problem, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's in a blank document, were I've added nothing yet. Then navigating finder is slow. :)

The video on reddit might make more sense.

Comment: @NicolasSeidenschnur welcome to tex.se! I think LyX 2.3.3 will be released in the next week. You might try that to see if it helps.